# responding to advice emails

Tags: email, employees

I have got a email regarding not to use fake emails from my team lead with project manager in cc of email.

Actually email used is not a fake email, its real email but email name is not standard(My company maintains standard in every thing and every work has to be neat). As they have sent me email professionally i need to reply them, so is it right to reply to email by just saying 'its not fake, its real email'.

I need some help in this.

Comment: Do you mean you have used a personal email address to reply to work email and that prompted this mail?

Comment: @Erik No, while testing application we need to use real email(created emails in google)but my email name was not so standard or convincing(ex: testingemail@gmail.com).

Comment: I suspect English is a second language for you.If they really thought the email was fake they would not have replied.

Answer (score 1):

First, explain the situation to your team lead and project manager like how you explained it to us:

> Despite the email not confirming to company standards for emails it is a real email address.

Then ask what or if there is a correct way of doing it:

> If the company has a standard for test/fake email names let me know and I will update it accordingly.

You can add some additional information to provide them access to the test email account if you think they will want to verify that the test email is in fact getting emails.

Comment: @Anketam should i apolalize for not using standard email address

Comment: I would say apologize for any confusion that this caused not necessarily because you did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The proper response to an advisory e-mail is always  "Oops, thanks for letting me know about my mistake." Possibly follows by "What should I have done instead?", If that isn't obvious.